# MongoDB Aggregator turn array into root keys values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My goal is to get the most recent updated key and re-create a user object with those updates.

I have the following data:

```
[{"_id":"5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6","createdAt":{"$numberLong":"1587834215451"}},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ea46e88c84e0bb1aaf510d7"},"documentId":"5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6","key":"name","value":"Jim Jenkins","type":"update","createdAt":{"$numberLong":"1587834215451"}},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ea46e88c84e0bb1aaf510d8"},"documentId":"5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6","key":"address.line1","value":"5638 Jackson Avenue","createdAt":{"$numberLong":"1587834215451"},"type":"update"},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ea4711bc84e0bb1aaf510d9"},"documentId":"5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6","key":"name","value":"Jim Jenkins the third","type":"update","createdAt":{"$numberLong":"1587834213451"}},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ea47298c84e0bb1aaf510da"},"documentId":"5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6","key":"name","value":"Bryan Jenkins","type":"update","createdAt":{"$numberLong":"1587835530397"}}]
```

And a pipeline that looks like this:

```
[{
    $match: {
        type: "update",
        documentId: "5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6"
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "createdAt": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "referenceId": "$referenceId",
            "key": "$key"
        },
        "top": {
            "$first": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$top.documentId",
        "key-values": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.key",
                "v": "$top.value"
            }
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$first": "$top.createdAt"
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        "from": "users",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "reference"
    }
}]
```

I have the following `key-values` in the pipeline:

```
{
    "key-values": [
        { k:"name", v:"Bryan Jenkins" },
        { k:"address.line1", v:"My Address"}
    ]
}
```

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
{
    "_id": "5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6"
    "name": "Bryan Jenkins",
    "address-line1": "My Address"
    "updatedAt": 1587835530397
}


//Or even better:
{
    "_id": "5ea46dcec84e0bb1aaf510d6"
    "name": "Bryan Jenkins",
    "address": {
        "line1": "My Address"
    },
    "updatedAt": 1587835530397
}
```

---

I can't for the life of me figure out how to replace the root by looping through the key-values. I've tried a series of `$replaceRoot` with `$mergeObjects` but can't seem to get it done because the key's in the key-values are completely unknown.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the sample document and the pipeline stages you have tried so far?

Comment: `"key-values":{"$push":{"k":"$_id.key","v":"$top.value"}}` -> with that I would say you might end up with either `{ k:"name", v:"Bryan Jenkins" }` or `{ k:"address.line1", v:"My Address"}` - So how did you get both pushed into an array ? Please edit question with more details..

Comment: @whoami Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your second `$group` stage with :

```
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$top.documentId",
      "key-values": {
        $mergeObjects: {
          $arrayToObject: [
            [
              {
                "k": "$_id.key",
                "v": "$top.value"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      "updatedAt": { "$first": "$top.createdAt" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$key-values",
          {
            _id: "$_id"
          },
          {
            updatedAt: "$updatedAt"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Just in case if you've more fields(not just `_id` & `updatedAt`) in root document which needs to be merge with `key-values` then :

```
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$top.documentId",
      "key-values": {
        $mergeObjects: {
          $arrayToObject: [
            [
              {
                "k": "$_id.key",
                "v": "$top.value"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      "updatedAt": { "$first": "$top.createdAt" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ "$key-values", "$$ROOT" ] } }
  },
  {
    $project: { "key-values": 0 }
  }
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qKdIhnNDZsR)

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes perfect sense